# Loading local images with Tauri

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tauri

Im trying to build a app using Tauri and React, it will have icons that can be changed replacing the default img by a new img, the problem is how can I load a image from a local directory an image, in this project Im using react with typescript

EDIT:
To extends my problem, when I try to load a image from react i got the next error in the developer tools: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

With the next code:

```
export type ItemType = "File" | "Folder"

interface ItemProps {
  itemType: ItemType,
  itemName: string | undefined
}

function Item(props: ItemProps) {

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={"$HOME/.config/miguel-file-manager/file_explorer_icons/icons8-file-48.png"}/>
      {props.itemName}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following to your `tauri.conf.json` file:

```json
{
    "$schema": "../node_modules/@tauri-apps/cli/schema.json",
    "tauri": {
        "allowlist": {
            "protocol": {
                "asset": true,
                "assetScope": [
                    "$DOCUMENT/**",
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A React component has to convert this local path into an asset path in order to render it:

```js
import { documentDir, join } from '@tauri-apps/api/path';
import { convertFileSrc } from '@tauri-apps/api/tauri';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function LocalImage() {
    const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState<string | null>(null);

    async function updatePaths() {
        setImagePath(convertFileSrc(await join(await documentDir(), 'some-dir', 'some-image.jpg')));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        updatePaths();
    }, []);

    return <img src={imagePath || ''} alt="Some Image" />;
}
```

If the image changes over time but the path stays constant, you can use the following to reload the image every 5 seconds:

```js
function LocalImage() {
    const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState<number>(new Date().getTime());

    async function updatePaths() {
        setImagePath(convertFileSrc(await join(await documentDir(), 'some-dir', 'some-image.jpg')));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        updatePaths();

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
        }, 5000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    return <img src={(imagePath || '') + `?${timestamp}`} alt="Some Image" />;
}
```